# Meaning of Super referencing interface in the code block

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

```
class GenericMaxException(Exception):
     """Base class for all Max layer exceptions."""

     def __init__(self, *, message):
         """
         Constructor.

         Parameters:
             Required:
                 message - String describing exception.

             Optional:
                 None
         """

         super().__init__(message)
```

Why do we need to pass message in super. Is the message an argument for any function in a class that GenericMaxException is inheriting from say Exception class . ? I know that super is referencing base class attributes.. but cannot understand why the message argument is called inside super .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default if nothing is passed using `super` when the exception is raised, there is no explanation, it only shows in the trace back where/which line raised the exception. But passing the message gives that explanation when the exception is raised.

Example 1:

```
class GenericMaxException(Exception):
    """Base class for all Max layer exceptions."""

    def __init__(self, * ,message):
        """
        Constructor.

        Parameters:
            Required:
                message - String describing exception.

            Optional:
                None
        """

        super().__init__()


raise GenericMaxException(message="This is the reason.")
```

Output :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/pythonTutorials/tutorials/temp.py", line 19, in <module>
    raise GenericMaxException(message="This is the reason.")
__main__.GenericMaxException  # No explanation why it occurred only mentioned is where it occurred
```

Example 2:

```
class GenericMaxException(Exception):
    """Base class for all Max layer exceptions."""

    def __init__(self, *, message):
        """
        Constructor.

        Parameters:
            Required:
                message - String describing exception.

            Optional:
                None
        """

        super().__init__(message)


raise GenericMaxException(message="This is the reason.")
```

Output :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/pythonTutorials/tutorials/temp.py", line 19, in <module>
    raise GenericMaxException(message="This is the reason.")
__main__.GenericMaxException: This is the reason. # Here is the explanation.
```